# format decimal to percent and truncate the rest

Tags: python, floating-point, python-2.x

Can someone help me format something like this:

```
0.774834437086
```

To:

```
77
```

I'm having a terrible time finding a solution by searching. I'm using Python 2.11. Multiplying by 100 gets me close (I still need to truncate), but i'd also like to round-up.
For example `0.776834437086` would round up to `78`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
round(x*100)
```

or

```
round(x,2)*100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num_1 = 0.774834437086
num_2 = 0.776834437086

percent_1 = int(round(num_1 * 100))
percent_2 = int(round(num_2 * 100))

percent_1: 77
percent_2: 78
```

Comment: The 'int' got rid of that pesky `.0` that I didn't want, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from math import ceil

d = Decimal("0.774834437086")
print(d)  # -> 0.774834437086
d = round(d, 2)
print(d)  # -> 0.77

d2 = Decimal("0.776834437086")
print(d2)  # -> 0.776834437086
d2 = ceil(d2*100)/100  # Round up to two (10**2==100) decimal places.
print(d2)  # -> 0.78
```

Note that `0.774834437086` would also round **up** to `.78`.